# How to show application logo in tablet but not in phone device

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am creating a application for both tablet and phone.
Now my Question is :
In app **I want to show application logo(i.e bigger than app icon) in tablet but not in phone devices.(In throught Application)**

That is android phone device with normal screen shows app icon and tablet shows app logo.
*Because tablet action bar have lot of space to show app logo but in phone it is not*

How could I differ both.when I run application?

I tried this in app manifeast :
`android:logo="@drawable/applogo"`
Am I want to use custom action bar with `ImageView` using Configuration...?
Also by following code I am recognising my device :

```
if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet))
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
        getActionBar().setLogo(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo));
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
 else
     {
        getActionBar().setLogo(null);
     }
```

Using above also logo not showing in tablet view.

Comment: add getActionBar().setLogo(null) for the false case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you to read [Android: Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). I'd recommend taking note to the chapter: **Using configuration qualifiers**. Basically you create different layout and drawable resources depending on the screen size (yes size, because there is no way to see if it is a tablet or a phone).

Comment: there is mentioned only for multiple screen support and not for action bar support.. So how..?(see updated Q. last line)

Comment: @PRAVIN you define your own style for the actionbar through a theme, this theme will then be different depending on the screen size.

Comment: your comment is answer for me.As I created differnet styles for action bar for tablet and mobile device and used @Kitesurfer suggesion too.

Answer (score 1):

Can be archived like this:

```
/**
 * Returns the value from the value folder which is actual. Do not cache the returned value as it might change on an
 * orientation change.
 * 
 * @param aContext
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isTablet(final Context aContext)
{
    return aContext.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
}
```

An place an boolean resource in folders like res/values-sw600dp for an 7" Tablet

Comment: OK. Thanks for suggestion...I have included code in my app.Will you like to help me more about Question..

Comment: I mean just set the logo when u read an value of true in your #onCreate Method

Comment: May I want to resize my logo drawable..But what should be dimension for logo.As I know about icons dimension in [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html)